# Nautilus file explorer to allow for NTFS parition mount

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, ntfs-3g

In older version of Ubuntu 18.04 if I recall you could see unmounted drive in nautilus side bar.
But now since I only see my home folder and other locations which is empty.
Is there a way to restore those unmounted drive to Nautilus and make them mountable by clicking on them  ?

Or is my only chance is to use the horrible dock available in Gnome Shell ?
Using the dock is very much not a solution as I do not use it at all.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].